# Replace seperator in Array[long] in the Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading a JSON file into a spark data frame in Scala. I have a JSON field like

```
"areaGlobalIdList":[2389,3,2,1,2147,2142,2518]
```

Spark is automatically inferring the datatype of this field as Array[long]. I tried `concat_ws`, but it seems only works with array[string]. When I tried converting this to array[string], the output is showing as

```
scala> val cmrdd = sc.textFile("/user/nkthn/cm.json")
scala> val cmdf = sqlContext.read.json(cmrdd)
scala> val dfResults = cmdf.select($"areaGlobalIdList".cast(StringType)).withColumn("AREAGLOBALIDLIST", regexp_replace($"areaGlobalIdList" , ",", "." ))
scala> dfResults.show(20,false)
```

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|AREAGLOBALIDLIST                                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@6364b584|
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm expecting the output to be

```
[2389.3.2.1.2147.2142.2518]
```

Any assistance is greatly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the `schema` of the `areaGlobalIdList` column as

```
 |-- areaGlobalIdList: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = false)
```

You can achieve this with simple `udf` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val concatWithDot = udf((array: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Long]) => array.mkString("."))

df.withColumn("areaGlobalIdList", concatWithDot($"areaGlobalIdList")).show(false)
```

Comment: My pleasure @Marsi :)